# Trouble with functions (javascript)

Tags: javascript, scope

I've built a working page with lots of javascript. The javascript is placed in between the `<head></head>` tags without a problem, but I really want to move it an external file.

I though I would be able to simply cut and paste all the code minus `<script></script>` tags but incuding `$(document).ready(function() {  });` it into a .js file and reference it in the usual way, but it's causing me big headaches. Can anyone suggest why I can't just do this?

As a compromise, I though I would detach at least some of my functions and put them in an external file but there are problems there too.

```
function look(){
  var word_id = $(this).attr("id");  
  //    Other stuff
  var   value = $(this).val();  
  //    Other stuff
}

$("input").focus(function(){look();});
```

In the above function, *this* is not the *this* it used to be when the code looked like this:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
  var word_id = $(this).attr("id");  
  //    Other stuff
  var   value = $(this).val();  
  //    Other stuff
});
```

I hope that a really clever person will spot my errors easily. Many thanks, Patrick.

Comment: What kind of headaches did you experience trying to move js code into the separate file? How did you reference this file? Are you sure your referenced scripts in the right order: jquery first, then your script?

Comment: The headache was that nothing happened! Why does jquery have to come first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function with no context specified, as you are calling `look()`, the `this` keyword inside that function will be the global object.

In your case you could only pass a reference to your function, and it will work properly:

```
$("input").focus(look);
```

Also, it might be helpful to know that the `this` keyword is not completely implicit, can be set explicitly by using the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) functions:

```
function test(arg1){
  alert(this + arg1);
}

test.call('hello ', 'world'); // will alert 'hello world'
```

And that the context (the `this` keyword) is set implicitly in the following cases:

1- When calling a function that is member of an object, eg.:

```
obj.myFunc(); // 'this' will refer to obj
```

2- When calling a function with the `new` operator:

```
var test = new Func(); // 'this' will refer to a new object
```

3- When calling a function not associated with any object:

```
foo();
// or
(function () {})(); // 'this' will be the global object
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code:

```
$("input").focus(look);
```

The problem is that when the `look` function was wrapped with an anonymous function the *this* pointer inside `look` was clobbered.  Here's a more explicit explanation:

```
$("input").focus(function() { 
    this; // Refers the DOM element jQuery is acting on
    // The _this_ pointer of the anonymous function is not passed to look.
    look(); // The _this_ pointer in look instead points to the window scope.
});
```

If for whatever reason you need to wrap a function call with anonymous function, you can use the `apply` or `call` to pass the *this* pointer of the outer scope to `look`.  Here's a quick example:

```
$("input").focus(function() { 
    ...
    look.apply(this);
    // This works too:
    // look.call(this);
});
```

The `call` and `apply` method are nearly identical.  They only difference in how they take  parameters.  Here's more info on [call and apply](http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/apply.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise putting your JS in the footer, so that you can ensure that will be only loaded after everything else on the page (DOM) is fully loaded.